# how to make Json data Using Json array in android

Tags: android

```
String orderdata="[
        {productid: 1, count: 2},
        {productid: 7, count: 7},
        {productid: 81, count 2}    
    ]"
String userId=2;
String slotdatetime=21/11/2015 5:00 PM
String address=204, Phase IV, Gurgaon
String total=2300;
```

This data i have available i have to make Json Format data like this

```
{
    userId: "2",
    slotdatetime: "21/11/2015 5:00 PM",  
    address: "204, Phase IV, Gurgaon",
    total: "2300",
    orderdata: [
        {productid: 1, count: 2},
        {productid: 7, count: 7},
        {productid: 81, count 2}    
    ]
}
```

But there is Problem to create Single  String in which i have get given data like this please help me .

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("userId", "2");
    json.put("slotdatetime", "21/11/2015 5:00 PM");
    json.put("address", "204, Phase IV, Gurgaon");
    json.put("total",2300);

JSONObject jsonorderdata = new JSONObject();
jsonorderdata.put("productid", "1");
jsonorderdata.put("count", "2");

JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
ja.put(jsonorderdata);

json.put("orderdata", ja);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce what you want:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {
    object.put("userId", userId);
    object.put("slotdatetime", slotdatetime);
    object.put("total", total);
    object.put("orderdata", new JSONArray(orderdata));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // handle exception
}
```

A couple notes before trying the above and reporting that it doesn't work:

1. your `String orderdata` can not be converted into a `JSONArray` as I've done above (`new JSONArray(orderdata)`) until you construct it so that it's actually valid.
2. `String userId` and `String total` would be better off as ints.